# setInterval throwing 'No overload matches this call'

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to call my function every x minutes, so I am using setInterval. But it gives me **No overload matches this call**. My code is like this:

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy......
    intervalId: number;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.intervalId = window.setInterval(this.test3(), 10000);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }

    test3() {
        console.log('test');
    }
```

**setInterval** line gives me this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
    Overload 1 of 2, '(handler: TimerHandler, timeout?: number, ...arguments: any[]): number', gave the following error.
        Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TimerHandler'.
    Overload 2 of 2, '(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: number, ...args: any[]): Timeout', gave the following error.
        Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => void'.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `setInterval()` expects the first argument to be a function which it can invoke, currently, you are passing the return value of `test3()` instead. You can use `setInterval(this.test3, 10000)` if you don't use `this` inside your `test3()` method, or `this.test3.bind(this)` if you plan on using `this`

Comment: @NickParsons this.test3.bind(this) solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function as the first parameter in `setInterval()`. Try this-

```
this.intervalId = window.setInterval(this.test3, 10000);
```

Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for `setInterval()` documentation.